# Setup OProfile on proprietary kernel

Tags: linux, profiling, kernel, oprofile

I'm trying to set up OProfile on our proprietary kernel with no success.
The kernel is based on: 2.6.34.8 running on mips74k CPU.

Is it possible to do so?

If so, I would really appreciate any guide that explains the step I should take.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In theory it's possible. Oprofile can be compiled as a kernel module. So you can try to build oprofile for 2.6.34.8 for mips74k and load it to your proprietary kernel. The problem is that there's no guaranty that proprietary kernel doesn't have any changes that can break oprofile.

Comment: how can I compile it as kernel module?